# Python Mysql CREATE and INSERT in one query

Tags: python, mysql

I am using Python to connect to MySQL in XAMPP.I am creating a string and passing it to a new process through queue.The string contains the MySQL query which on execution will create a table and insert into the table.following is my code:-

```
from MySQLdb import connect
from os import _exit
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
q=Queue()

def pkt():
    conn=connect(user='root',passwd='257911.',host='localhost',unix_socket="/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock")
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    conn.select_db("try")
    while True:
        y=q.get()
        if y=="exit":
            break
        else:
            cursor.execute(y)
            conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    _exit(0)


if __name__=="__main__":
    a=Process(target=pkt)
    a.start()
    query="CREATE TABLE hello(id varchar(10) NOT NULL,name varchar(20)); INSERT INTO hello(id,name) VALUES('1234','sujata'); "
    q.put(query)
    q.put("exit")
```

Upon executing the code, I am getting the following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "try.py", line 16, in pkt
    conn.commit()
ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

I am getting the same error on inserting into multiple tables in one query.Is it not possible to combine create and insert in one statement??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to close the cursor after execution. This works for me.

```
from MySQLdb import connect
from os import _exit
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
q=Queue()

def pkt():
    conn=connect(user='root',host='localhost',unix_socket="/home/mysql/mysql/mysql.sock")
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    conn.select_db("try")
    while True:
        y=q.get()
        if y=="exit":
            break
        else:
            cursor.execute(y)
            cursor.close()
            conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    _exit(0)


if __name__=="__main__":
    a=Process(target=pkt)
    a.start()
    query="CREATE TABLE hello(id varchar(10) NOT NULL,name varchar(20)); INSERT INTO hello(id,name) VALUES('1234','sujata'); "
    q.put(query)
    q.put("exit")
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot give multiple semicolon separated queries in the same line. This is because `MySQLdb` is a wrapper around `_mysql` which makes it compatible with the Python DB API interface (Read more about the API [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)). The API works via `PREPARE/EXECUTE` statements and according to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/prepare.html),

> The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements.

Comment: @sujata Did that answer your question?